# Implement a persistent bar on mobile when user navigates off my site?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, iframe

We have a requirement to keep a navigation bar at the top of the screen when users go to an off-site page.  This would normally be easily implemented by putting the new page into an iframe.

The problem comes when implementing this on mobile platforms, such as iPhone and Android.

Is there any way to tell an iframe to scale its' content to fit the width of the page the way  a normal web page does?